# Team City build - Workspace is null error

Tags: maven, teamcity-8.0

I am setting up Maven project from a RTC repository on Team City. When I run the build on the project I am getting the following error:

"`Failed to perform checkout on agent: Unable to start build as workspace name is null`"

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this error.

More Details for the error:

- Updating sources: agent side checkout
- [VCS Root: Trunk] Agent Checkout
- [Agent Checkout] Unable to start build as workspace name is null
- [Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: Unable to start build as workspace name is null

Answer (score 1):

Please check that build configuration has at least one build step (it can be a dummy or simple echo message).

I did face the same issue and could resolve it by creating a dummy step.